# Is it possible to pack Spark code into libraries without the main function

Tags: apache-spark

Untill now, I've only used Spark for writing application with the main function in it. But what I would like to do now is to create Spark based libraries (with RDD/Dataframe operations and stuff), which can then be called from other applications. Is it possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course this is possible. For instance, take a look at [GraphFrames](https://github.com/graphframes/graphframes) or any library at [Spark Packages](https://spark-packages.org/).